# How to add a node to a taxonomy term?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have searched long and hard for this, but I cannot figure out how to add a node to a taxonomy term.

I have taxonomy (Region) with term (North America) and I am trying to add the node (USA) to North America.

Could someone please teach me how this can be done? I just cannot find it anywhere on Drupal 7 Admin controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a 'Term reference' field on the relevant content type:

1. Go to http://mysite.com/admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields (where 'page' is the name of your content type).
2. Add a new field, using 'Term reference' as the field type.
3. On the next page, choose the vocabulary you want the content type to reference.
4. On the page after that, choose specific settings for the field.

Next time you go to add/edit a node of that content type, you'll be able to choose terms from your selected vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you don't add nodes to taxonomy. You instead tag node with a term reference from a vocabulary. So you need to add a field to your node content type, a field of type "Term reference", and on the edit form for USA you will be able to select North America.